# STL container that combines sequential ordering with constant access time?

Tags: c++, stl

This strikes me as something I should have been able to find on Stackoverflow, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms here.

I have the scenario where there is a class

```
class Foo
{
  int key;
  int b;
  ...
}
```

and I want to push new elements of that class onto a list. Number of items is unknown beforehand.

At the same time, I want to be able to quickly check the existence of (and retrieve) an element with a certain key, e.g. key==5.

So, to summarize:

- It should have O(1) (or thereabouts) for existence/retrieval/deletion
- It should retain the order of the pushed items

One solution to this strikes me a "use a std::list to store the items, and std::unordered_map to retrieve them, with some book-keeping". I could of course implement it myself, but was wondering whether something like this already exists in a convenient form in STL.

EDIT: To preempt the suggestion, std::map is *not* a solution, because it orders based on some key. That is, it won't retain the ordering in which I pushed the items.

Comment: There's nothing like that in the STL, or the modern C++ standard library (which I assume is what you meant by STL), but Boost has [multi-index containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: O(1) is the tricky part, std::map is O(log) at least. Once you have that, storing pointers to elements in a std::vector or a linked list would solve the second constraint.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is “almost” O(1).  So the idea using it together with a `std::list` is a reasonable approach to meet the OP's complexity requirements.  Of course, using Boost will probably be a more robust approach.  Of course, it can take a huge *n* until asymptotic complexity becomes dominant in practice, so measuring performance will be very important.

Comment: This "O" notation can be tricky. O(n) doesn't mean that it's always slower than O(1), just that, for some value of n or greater, it becomes slower. For simple types (such as class with basic data types), and less than perhaps 1000 of them (depends on many factors, such as size of type and CPU), you may find that a `std::vector` using `std::find` is significantly faster than other more "clever" data structures which promise "better" O ratings. This is due to better cache performance and less dynamic memory allocations. (Eg a `std::list` dynamically allocates every node. Very slow.)

Comment: Of course the only way to know for sure is to measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL does not have the kind of container, you may write your own using std::unordered_map and std::list. Map your keys to the list iterators in std::unordered_map and store key-value pairs in std::list.

```
void add(const Key& key, const Value& value) 
{
    auto iterator = list.insert(list.end(), std::pair<Key, Value>(key, value));
    map[key] = iterator;
}

void remove(const Key& key)
{
    auto iterator = map[key];
    map.erase(key);
    list.erase(iterator);
}
```

Or use boost multi-index container
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured it would come down to. I am actually surprised it's that straightforward in code.
I take it the iterators in a list do not get invalidated through anything but a delete? (unlike in maps where rehashing invalidates all iterators)

Comment: Yes, you are right, only iterators, which point to deleted objects become invalid in std::list.

Comment: BTW, any particular reason for storing the key alongside the value in the list as a pair? It seems one could just as well only store the element itself in the list, thus reducing memory.

Comment: You should store pairs if you want to iterate keys.

Comment: I see, yeah. In my particular case the key is part of the element itself, so the retrieval of it would give you the key alongside with it.